# Determine where the Cauchy Riemann conditions are satisfied for $w=\overline{z}$ (the complex conjugate of $z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a question in my complex analysis worksheet.

Determine where the Cauchy Riemann conditions are satisfied for $w=\overline{z}$ (the complex conjugate of $z$).

As far as I know the function has to be differentiable for Cauchy Riemann condition to hold. But the conjugate of $z$, hasn't got a limit, so it's non differentiable. So I'm wondering how does it hold?

If assuming it is actually differentiable. $w=\overline{z}$, then $w = u+iv,$ and $z=x+iy$.

Since its a conjugate, it would be $z=x-iy$? In this case, what would $u$ and $v$ be?

If I know what $u$ and $v$ is then I can calculate the Cauchy Riemann Conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w=\overline{z}$$ $$u+iv=x-iy.$$
The Cauchy-Riemann equations are:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

We have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1 \text{ and }\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-1,$$

so the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied nowhere.